# RegEx - Match Only Strings That Have a Dollar Sign At Their Beginning

Tags: regex, search, replace, pcre

I have been trying to accomplish this for hours, but I am still in the beginning of learning RegEx so reaching out to the experts here for help.
How can I match only the strings that have a dollar sign in their beginning?
I already achieved partial success with this regex:

```
(?<=\$)\[(?=[^\]]*[a-z])([a-zA-Z_]+[\w]+)\]
```

On this code block:

```
<?php
$options[$list[_capture_me]][]=array($list[_captureme],$list[_capture_me]);
      $option_names[$list[_capture_me]]=$list[_captureme];
      $product_name=$list[capture_me];
$product_name=$list[0];
$product_name=$list[DONTCAPTUREME];
$product_name=$list[CapTureMe];
$product_name=$list[CapTurEME];
            $actionKey = $get[DONT_CAPTURE_ME];

        if(array_key_exists(DONT_CAPTURE_ME,$get)) {
            $actionKey = $get[DONT_CAPTURE_ME];
            if(array_key_exists($actionKey,$this->arrPageActions)){
                    $this->arrAllTemplatesAndAttributes[$templateID][captureme]['Capture_Me'][$res[option_values_id]] = $res[DONT_CAPTURE_ME];
$old_faq_id.="$result[faq_id]&";    
      $result['toc']="<b><a href=$PHP_SELF#$result[faq_id]>$result['question']</a></b>";}
 $result['toc']="<b><a href=$PHP_SELF#$result[faq_id]>$result[QUESTION]</a></b>";}
$login_groups_id = $check_admin[login_groups_id];
?>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->

function check_input(field_name, field_size, message) {
  if ($elements[capture_me] && (form.elements[dont_capture].type != "hidden") && $form.elements[capture_me]) {
    var field_value = form.elements[dontcapture].value;
  var field_value = $form.elements[captureme].value;

    if (field_value == '' || field_value.length < field_size) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message + "\n";
      error = true;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/I91TNn/11/), it also matches strings inside the bracket, even when they don't have the dollar sign at their beginning and I need to prevent that.
I tried adding positive lookbehind like so:

```
(?<=\$\w+)
```

But that doesn't work in this engine, errors:

> a quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

Is there any way to achieve this?

By the way, I am doing this because my ultimate goal is to add single-quotes to all the strings in the brackets, using substitution, so lines like this `$product_name=$list[CapTureMe];` will become `$product_name=$list['CapTureMe'];` for example, using this:

```
['\1']
```

[DEMO #2](https://regex101.com/r/I91TNn/12/)

Thank you

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5OeJSw/1 Like this?

Comment: Wow. Looks good, but it still didn't match `$form.elements[capture_me]` for example

Comment: Is that even valid PHP syntax? I thought `.` was string concatenation.

Comment: You are right, it's not valid php or js at all, just something I was testing. Please post your answer, let me thank you somehow :)

Comment: I don't see any text like `$[asdfasf]` , why are you trying to match that sequence ?

Comment: Why are you obsessed with lookbehind width problems ? Just add `(\$\w+)(\[...\])` Replace `$1 ... $2`

Comment: @sln, thank you, I have just begun to learn regex a few days ago, not obsessed with anything, just still very green, but learning

Comment: Then lookbehind may be over your head for now, do the simple stuff first.

Comment: ok, sounds like a good advice, thanks

Comment: Regex is not a tool to parse complex languages. PHP has a [tokenizer](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php), use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple cases you can use

```
(\$\w+)\[(\w*[a-z]\w*)\]
```

as your regex and

```
$1['$2']
```

as the replacement.

The regex in detail:

- `\$\w+` matches a `$` sign, followed by 1 or more word characters (letters, digits, underscore)
- `(` `)` captures the matched string (#1)
- `\[` matches a literal `[`
- `\w*[a-z]\w*` matches 0 or more word characters, followed by a lowercase letter, followed by 0 or more word characters (i.e. we're matching a word that contains at least one lowercase letter somewhere)
- `(` `)` captures the matched string (#2)
- `\]` matches a literal `]`

We replace this by

- `$1` - the contents of the first capture buffer
- `['` - literally the two characters `[` and `'`
- `$2` - the contents of the second capture buffer
- `']` - literally the two characters `'` and `]`

You can get more fancy if needed (this can get quickly out of hand):

```
((?:\$|->)\w+)\[(\w*[a-z]\w*)\]
```

also allows `->` at the beginning instead of `$`. This would match e.g. `->bar[baz]` in `$foo->bar[baz]`.

Another possible addition could be

```
((?:\$|->)\w+(?:\[\$\w+\])*)\[(\w*[a-z]\w*)\]
```

The `(?:\[\$\w+\])*` part allows 0 or more bracketed variable names between the initial identifier and the unquoted word at the end. This would match e.g. `$foo[$bar][$baz][quux]` (with `$foo[$bar][$baz]` in `$1` and `quux` in `$2`).

However, none of these solutions would match both `bar` and `baz` in `$foo[bar][baz]`. It's a non-trivial task because it would require overlapping matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way to make it also match cases like `$foo[bar][baz]`? My regex in the question does. So that it will find and convert it to `$foo['bar']['baz']`

Comment: @CM웃 I guess you could do something like `(?:\$\w+|\])\[\K(\w*[a-z]\w*)(?=\])` (replace by `'$1'`) (using `\K` to emulate variable-width look-behind), but that doesn't really validate the match, it just looks for either a variable `$foo` or a `]`, followed by some unquoted index `[foo]`.

Comment: Another option I was thinking about, is to use my regex from the question and add to it a multi-line check to see if the code is php code, ie. if it's between `<?php` and `?>` only, otherwise it will fail. Any suggestion how to achieve this check combined with my regex?

Comment: @CM웃 I can construct all kinds of scenarios where this approach (and my regex) fails. If you want to transform arbitrary code, I'd go with an actual parser (or at least tokenizer). If you cram the whole thing into a single regex, you're going to have a bad time.